# How do I make an extrusion without having a subdivision on an object like a square?

Tags: extrude

I saw a tutorial where a square was created without any subdivision. How can I do the same?

I extruded a square after selecting its face in editing mode. It had a subdivision and I want a square or any object that extrudes without one.Tried different approaches like adding a modifier but with no success.

That is the square on the right I extruded and it added a subdivision
[image: That is the square on the right I extruded and it added a subdivision]

I want my square to extrude like this one without a subdivsion
[image: I want my square to extrude like this one without a subdivsion]

Comment: Hello could you please link the tutorial?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address the raised issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the *Dissolve Orthogonal Edges* checkbox in the *Operator Panel*. Below are some screenshots of it unchecked and checked:

Unchecked:
[image: Before]

Checked:
[image: After]

Comment: Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

It's also called Extrude Manifold. If you hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> instead of <kbd>E</kbd>, you can choose it from the menu and it extrudes with Dissolve Orthogonal Edges enabled.

[image]